# Batch Editing of a Table Using Checkboxes on Left

Tags: html, forms

I have check boxes in the far left hand column in a table and would like to use these to perform batch edits on the contents of the table. For example a user would like to edit multiple items in the table: They check the ones they want to edit, and then go to the drop down at the bottom of the table to select what they'd like to change one of the columns to. When they hit submit I would check for boxes that are checked and modify the associated columns. The image below shows this visually.

[image: example]

The checkboxes I are not in any  and are solely checkboxes. I'm assuming this is the correct thing to do as I do not the whole table being part of the form. My question then is, how would I submit the checkboxes when "Submit" is pressed, so that I can check which checkboxes are used?

Answer (score 0):

Move the form tag to the top of the table and then the checkboxes will be included in the POST request.